# WPF FlowDocument print aligning content by half of the A4

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I have a print button with code:

```
            PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();

            FlowDocumentPageViewer docpv = new FlowDocumentPageViewer();

            FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
            doc.PagePadding = new Thickness(10);                
            doc.PageWidth = 793;// a4 width in px
           
         
            Section sec = new Section();
            



            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(Setup.GUI_texts_collection[193] + " " + vInvoice.Id.ToString()));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(10);
            p.FontSize = 30;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            p.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;               
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(this.Type_lbl.Content + ":  " + this.TypeComboBox.Text));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            p.FontSize = 20;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(this.Code_lbl.Content + ":  " + vInvoice.Code));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            p.FontSize = 20;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(this.Date_lbl.Content + ":  " + this.DateTextBox.Text));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            p.FontSize = 20;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(this.Sender_lbl.Content + ":  " + this.SenderComboBox.Text));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            p.FontSize = 20;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(this.Receiver_lbl.Content + ":  " + this.ReceiverComboBox.Text));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            p.FontSize = 20;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(this.From_stock_lbl.Content + ":  " + this.From_stockComboBox.Text));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            p.FontSize = 20;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(this.To_stock_lbl.Content + ":  " + this.To_stockComboBox.Text));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            p.FontSize = 20;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(this.Cash_lbl.Content + ":  " + this.Paid_by_cashTextBox.Text));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            p.FontSize = 20;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(this.Bank_lbl.Content + ":  " + this.Paid_by_bankTextBox.Text));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            p.FontSize = 20;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(this.Debt_lbl.Content + ":  " + this.DebtTextBox.Text));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            p.FontSize = 20;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run(this.Total_amount_lbl.Content + ":  " + this.Total_amountTextBox.Text));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            p.FontSize = 20;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            sec.Blocks.Add(p);

            
            //// Create first Paragraph  
            doc.Blocks.Add(sec);




            doc.Name = "FlowDoc";
            IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;


        
            if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Invoice " + vInvoice.Id.ToString());
            }
```

But as result I get folowing document[Printed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw9K4.jpg)

So, why  p.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;  not moving first paragraph to center of the document. It looks like it puts it at the center of the half of the document.
What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the page is being set up with two columns.  Your title is being centred in the first of the two columns.

I was able to fix it by adding the line

```cs
            doc.ColumnWidth = doc.PageWidth;
```

after

```cs
            doc.PageWidth = 793;// a4 width in px
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.columnwidth) for the `ColumnWidth` property states that the default value is `NaN` and that this causes only one column to be displayed, but it seems that a `NaN` value does not work, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes it is strange why it happens, but it solved my issue.